# Can't collect null from Object.values

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

When I created a string of values from collection, the value null is not carried through. I need to have null appended to my string only if it is a value of the object collection[i]. Or at least why null isn't being carried through would be appreciated.

```
function truthCheck(collection, pre) {
  // Is everyone being true?
  var arr = '';
  for ( i=0; i<collection.length; i++ ){
    if ( pre in collection[i]){
      arr += ' ' + Object.values(collection[i]);//Problem is here
    }
  }
  arr += null; //If I append it after..
  return arr; //This returns as I want it to. This return is for testing 
              //only.
  arr = arr.trim();
  var regex = /NaN|null|0|undefined|false/;
  arr = arr.split(" ");
  for ( i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    if( arr[i].search(regex) != -1 ){
      arr.splice(i,1);
    }
  }
  if ( arr.length == collection.length ){
    return true;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}

truthCheck([{"name": "Pete", "onBoat": true}, {"name": "Repeat", "onBoat": 
true}, 
{"name": "FastFoward", "onBoat": null}], "onBoat");
```

Comment: Still not really sure what you're asking... what is your desired output?

Comment: Are you looking for `arr.every(x => x.onBoat)` or `arr.filter(x => x.onBoat).map(x => x.name)` ?

Comment: Well in your example onBoat is `in` all collections, you will also need to check the value for truthy too.  eg.  `if ( pre in collection[i] && collection[i][pre]){`   The first part pre in collection[i] is seeing if 'onBoat' is a property, and then collection[i][pre] is seeing if it's true.

Comment: filter.map is a much simpler way to do what it i'm trying to do. But all the same, how would I get a null value (onBoat:null) from an array of objects that was piped in as a parameter. @georg

Comment: I want "return arr;" just after the first for loop to return "Pete,true Repeat,true, FastForward,null"

Comment: @DevinElder: maybe, but I still fail to grasp what you're trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 0):

Keith nailed it on the head. Adding && collection[i][pre] reduced my string to the point regex would filter the array properly.

```
for ( i=0; i<collection.length; i++ ){
  if ( pre in collection[i] && collection[i][pre] ){
    arr += ' ' + Object.values(collection[i]);
  }
}
```